# Too many data on database - "replication" decision needed

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Now I have a problem with a MySQL application. Actually I'm worried about a problem I might have in a few months.

Here's the scenario: I'm developing a web application that will have a lot of clients using it. It's a application that has a unique core and several adaptations (running on the same core), so the database is the same for all adaptations. Each adaptation has one or more clients using it.

So, my database has more than 200 tables and some tables may have more than 500 rows per day per client. I'm worried that when the database get too big the selects may be really expensive.

I was thinking about create several databases (identical schema) and the application should decide what database to use based on what client is logged. But I'll have really problems to update the schemas (I'll have to update each database). My application can choose the database, it's not a problem.

- Do you think that the MySQL can really stop if it has a lot of data?
- Is there a way to easily update several identical-schema-databases?
- Master/slave approach solves my problem?

I think it's important you to know that in all tables I have a collumn that tells me to what client that row belongs to and always use it in all the select queries as a WHERE clause.

So what I need help is to decide what to do. Can you help me with these questions? Do you have any other smarter solution?

I don't know if it's important but I'm using PHP.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

1. Stop is a big word, but it can become slow. From what I read here though, you won't have a "lot" of data. It's more about size in memory so you should focus on that more than the amount of rows. Just take care of your indexes.
2. There are systems to manage this, but it depends how/where you get your database structure. I assume you change your schemas with an SQL query however, it shouldn't be too hard to automatically execute that query on all database right? If they will be different machines than Fabric could help.
3. If it's about too much reads, yes, it will solve your problem.

**Note**

From what I've read so far you don't have that much data, nothing that MySQL can't handle for the years to come.

Answer (score 1):

500 rows per day is fine, that's not a high load.

Multiple clients in the database/ or databases, is called a "multi-tenancy system". Keeping multiple tenancies in the same database is a little bit trickier, but do-able.

You'll need to define *indexes* for your tables, which should mostly include the client ID as well as whatever other columns.

You'll probably also want to denormalize the client ID & make it available as a column in all your major tables.. so you can put it in your indexes.

MySQL didn't use to have perfect reliability. It's better these days and I'm not going to recommend changing/another DB to you, especially as you're on PHP, but make sure you run an automatic backup regularly (say every night).